# jquery Function is undefined

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head><script scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script> </head>
<div id="cont1">
<select id="sel1" name="sel1" multiple>
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
<option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#sel1 option').on('click', function(e){
if($(this).is(':selected')){
$('<input value="'+$(this).val()+'" />').appendTo('#cont1');
}
});
});
</script>
<html>
</body>
<html>
```

Why is this function not working? It gives the error 'function not defined'.

Comment: You have no opening `<body>` tag.

Comment: And `scr` instead of `src` on the `<script>`

Comment: @NRohler is right because it is working fine in fiddle

Comment: Horrible code formatting, you are ending a body that which has no beginning. Fix your formatting and have another close look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct attribute name is `src`:

```
         v-------------- correct the attribute name
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also you should check your markup, since the correct one must contain the `<body>` tag and one correctly placed pair of `<html></html>` tag.

Additionally, consider using [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event for `<select>` element instead of `click` for `<option>`, since it is more 'cross browser'.

Comment: Also there are three opening html tags.

Comment: @undefined Yeah, I skipped that :)

Comment: Sorry guys writing mistake, so sorry about this silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have to write src, btw $(document).ready(function() { is better.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sel1 option').on('click', function(e){
            if($(this).is(':selected')){
                $('<input value="'+$(this).val()+'" />').appendTo('#cont1');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cont1">
        <select id="sel1" name="sel1" multiple>
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And why would `document.ready` be "better". `$(function({ })` is just a shorthand that does exactly the same thing

Comment: Because it's more readable. You copied his html formatting bugs over btw

Comment: lol really i'm getting minus 1, because I help someone ROFL. Yes Johan it's better because it's more readable. sorry for format :)

Answer (score 0):

Tip: format the code never hurts.

Also, check [HTML reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) to improve your code. **scr**, many **body** tags, etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#sel1 option').on('click', function(e){
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                $('<input value="'+$(this).val()+'" />').appendTo('#cont1');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cont1">
        <select id="sel1" name="sel1" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey its working fine, but what if i also want that when user unselect or unclick the option from dropdown it removes respective textbox ?

Comment: @user1640566 hello, you can did like I do in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLamM/)